# Changing the sortDescriptor of a FetchedResultsController dynamically. Ideas?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

I'm having difficulty understanding how to update my fetchedresultscontroller with a new sort. I initialize a frc the standard way in my class. But how exactly do you modify the fetchrequest with a new sortdecription?  My app has a sort selector in the appSettings that the user can change on the fly.  Is there a way to update the frc dynamically?  The code below is what I have in the viewWillLoad callback, but it just produces a blank table.  Thanks!

```
[self appSettingSortOrder];     
if (sortOrderChanged) {

    //Form a new fetchrequest for the FRC and reload the table.

    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Aircraft" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:currentSortOrder ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error];

    [self.tableView reloadData];

    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];      
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, the immediate problem with this code is that while you create a new fetch request you never assign it to the FRC.

It doesn't matter because you can't change an FRC's fetch request on the fly. The `NSFetchedResultsController` docs make this explicit.

> Important: You must not modify the
>   fetch request. For example, you must
>   not change its predicate or the sort
>   orderings.

To change the sort ordering of an FRC, you must create a new FRC with a new fetch request with the new ordering.

Comment: I read that too.  So it would seem that I need create a new FRC with a new sort order and assign it's delegate to the class that has the callbacks, ie self.  Probably prudent to assign the current FRC to nil.  Yes/no?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the value of sortOrderChanged is false. The fetch is not being performed. Set a breakpoint on the if block to make sure it is entering.